# Is There a Better Way to Code Conditional Custom Product Tabs in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a custom product tab for the single product pages in Woocommerce using the [code sample from Woocommerce's site](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/).

I want the custom tab to display conditionally only if there is content for it. To accomplish that, I'm using the following code:

```
// Set a global variable for the custom tab content to pass it to the callback function that displays the tab content.
$features_tab_content = '';
function woo_new_product_tab($tabs) {
    global $post, $features_tab_content;
    $custom_fields = array(
        'field_one'=>'Field One', 
        'field_two'=>'Field Two'
    );
    $fields_to_display = array();
    foreach ($custom_fields as $fieldname=>$fieldtitle) {
            $$val = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $fieldname, true );
            if ($$val != '') {
                $fields_to_display[$fieldtitle] = $$val;
            }
    }
    if (count($fields_to_display) > 0) {
        $features_tab_content = '<h2>Product Features</h2><table class="shop_attributes"><tbody>';
        foreach ($fields_to_display as $fieldtitle=>$val) {
            $features_tab_content .= '<tr><th>' . $fieldtitle . '</th><td>' . $val . '</td></tr>';
        }
        $features_tab_content .= '</tbody></table>';
        $tabs['features'] = array(
                'title' => __( 'Features', 'woocommerce' ),
                'priority' => 20,
                'callback' => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
            );
    }
    return $tabs;
}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    global $features_tab_content;
    echo $features_tab_content;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
```

The code tests for the existence of content for the custom tab in the `woo_new_product_tab` function and uses the variable called `$features_tab_content` to hold the actual content.

The problem is that I couldn't figure out how to pass the content to the callback function that actually displays the content, so I made the `$features_tab_content` variable global within the functions and used it in the callback function `woo_new_product_tab_content`.

It seems kind of clumsy, but it's better than testing for the content in both functions. I don't want to use a plugin to do this, but I'm wondering if there's not a cleaner way to code it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of the meta you are planning to display when you are filtering the $tabs:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
   global $post;

   if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'field_one', true ) || get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'field_two', true ) ){
    // Adds the new tab

    $tabs['features'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Features', 'stackoverflow' ),
        'priority'  => 20,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
   }
    return $tabs;

}
```

The callback without global variables:

```
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    global $post;

    $custom_fields = array(
            'field_one'=>'Field One', 
            'field_two'=>'Field Two'
    );

    $fields_to_display = array();

    foreach ($custom_fields as $fieldname=>$fieldtitle) {
        $$val = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $fieldname, true );
        if ($$val != '') {
            $fields_to_display[$fieldtitle] = $$val;
        }
    }

    // The new tab content
    if (count($fields_to_display) > 0) {
        echo '<h2>Product Features</h2><table class="shop_attributes"><tbody>';

        foreach ( $fields_to_display as $fieldtitle => $val ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . $fieldtitle . '</th><td>' . $val . '</td></tr>';
        }

        echo '</tbody></table>';

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that would be the same kind of situation I'm in now. I'd still have to create the content in woo_new_product_tab and pass it as a global variable.

Comment: No, you'd build the content in `woo_new_product_tab_content()`. Whether this is more efficient I couldn't say, but it doesn't require a global.

Comment: I think it would be less efficient than using the global because I'd be making the calls with get_post_meta to get the meta values in both functions instead of just one.

Comment: True, but you could mitigate that by hooking into `save_post and saving 1 single meta field... something like `_show_features_tab` if any of the relevant fields have data. Then you are only checking 1 meta in each function *and* aren't using a global.